# How to Redirect example.com/blog/month/post to example.com/post

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I recently created a new droplet to use with Serverpilot. So, I created a new droplet and migrated contents from my old droplet using All in one WP migration plugin. In the permalink settings I have maintained the previous permalink structure which was example.com/post-name and saved the settings.

But, all of a sudden, I can see Organic traffic (search engine traffic) to example.com/blog/dd-mm-yy/post-name which is obviously returning not found 404 page.

I don't know if it is a temporary issue, as I have correct permalink structure setup already.

Now I want to redirect any traffic coming to example.com/blog/date/post-name to example.com/post name. For all the posts. Basically, I want to strip off /blog/dd-mm-yy from all the posts so that the user can be redirected to example.com/post-name.

Any way to do it from .htaccess?

.htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] RewriteRule ^blog/(?:\d+/)+/([^/]+/?)$ /blog/$1 [L,NC,R=301] 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `/.htaccess` have this rule as **very first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

RewriteRule ^blog/(?:\d+/)+/([^/]+/?)$ /blog/$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi Anubhav, thanks for the reply.. I have edited the question. I want to redirect example.com/blog/dd-mm-yy/post-name to example.com/post-name...

So, should I add the following rules right?

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^data/(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L,NC,R=301]

Comment: Hi Anubhav, the post URL is something like this >> http://www.example.com/blog/2016/01/06/postname sorry for not making it right in the question. 

So, I have added the updated rules, but I see the site is not being redirected... is this because of wrong date format? do i need to make any changes to the rules again?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I couldn't get it to work. I ended up manually redirecting all the post using redirection plugin.

Comment: However, I would like to add that, I never created /blog subfolder for my website. It must have been added by the theme and was just a category I guess. Hence, your suggestion didn't work.

Comment: Hi anubahv, see this:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(?:\d+/)+/([^/]+/?)$ /blog/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

this is how it should look like, right?